# Several behaviours according to subtype

Tags: c#

Let's say I have an interface

```
public interface IA
{
    double PerformCalculation();
}
```

and a

```
public class C
{
    public IA ia {get; set;}
    public double DoCalculation()
    {
        return ia.SomeFunctionToImplement();
    }
}
```

By subtypes I mean classes implementing this interface. The idea behind `PerformCalculation` is that it is a function doing an intensive numerical computation in subtypes implementing it, following a numerical algorithm. My problem is that I have some subtypes for which, in addition to the numerical algorithm, there is a formula allowing to skip the numerical algorithm, so that for these subtypes I have a choice : either the algorithm or the formula.

What are ways/"designs" allowing me for keeping track of this choice ?

Comment: Object orientation?

Comment: Add an additional property on your interface to specify this choice.

Comment: The question is: Who is to decide whether to use the one or the other path? In principle, you would just have two different subclasses for this, one which implements the numerical algorithm, and one that uses the formula. Then, depending on which class is used, you'll have one or the other.

Comment: @ChristophHerold I updated the question : it's the class `C` that uses `PerformCalculation` according to it's `ia` member. I understand your point of "one subclass per type of calculation", but what worries me is that basically wherever I have this choice in my code, I will have to develop (and not to forget to develop it) subclasses.

Comment: 'SomeFunctionToImplement' is not a method of interface IA.

Comment: Again, who is supposed to decide, which method to use when? As long as that is not clear, we can only make educated guesses as to what would make sense in your case.

Comment: @ChristophHerold The client using class `C` is the one who will decide.

Comment: @PhillipNgan I never used the term "method".

Comment: In your example `C` is not aware of the concrete implementation of 'IA' (which would be the subtype you are refering to), therefore `C` is not in a position to decide how the subtype calculates its stuff. You may find it useful to look at the strategy pattern, maybe with a little rearrangement of your classes and interfaces it might help solve your problem. A brief description and example can be found here: https://exceptionnotfound.net/strategy-the-daily-design-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

> I have some subtypes for which, in addition to the numerical
>   algorithm, there is a formula allowing to skip the numerical
>   algorithm,

What you are essentially asking for is to embed in the contract a side effect you wish the concrete implementations provide. e.g. the implementation is fast; it is slow; it is light on resources. Interfaces, in so far as being a language feature enforceable by the compiler, cannot enforce side effects. So the only way to "keep track of this choice" is by suggesting hints using a naming convention. If the caller really cares about the side-effect, you might define an interface like:

```
interface IA 
{
   void PerformAlgorithm();
   void PeformFormula();
}
```

This is a terrible solution, but you don't have any attractive choices for the enforcement of side-effects at an interface level. At least the caller now has the ability to choose which method to call, but must trust the implementer of the concrete class to be true to the suggestive names.

Comment: You could also add a property `bool IsFormulaSupported { get; }` to let the executor know, if this implementation actually offers this functionality. But, I agree, this is an ugly solution.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that this can violate Liskov Substitution Principle, it would be a better alternative to have some sort of object orientation or two interfaces where one is for algorithm, the other for formula.

Comment: Maybe he could have an abstract class that has a method that does algorithm / formula choosing? The abstract class would contain abstract methods Algorithm, Formula that the concrete implementations need to implement? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members

Answer (score 0):

You could enhance your `class C` with a FormulaIA:

```
public class C
{
    public IA NumericalIA { get; set; }
    public IA FormulaIA { get; set; }

    public double DoCalculation()
    {
        if (this.FormulaIA != null && ShouldUseFormula()) // ShouldUseFormula is your logic for deciding
        {
            return this.FormulaIA.PerformCalculation();
        }
        else
        {
            return this.NumericalIA.PerformCalculation();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, whoever creates your class C can fill either only one or both implementations, and your class can decide, which one to use.

This is not much different to having the interface implement both methods, but it won't clutter your implementations that do not support the formula approach with unnecessary methods.

Comment: How would strategy pattern help me here, though ? is it just rendering the `if else` opp by doing subclasses instead or ?

Comment: Indeed. Maybe, you can provide a more detailed example of what you really want to achieve.

Comment: @ChristophHerold I will indeed try to create a formal example from my concrete situation and will update my question with it.